# Solidity inheritance can't read parent's value correctly

Tags: solidity, truffle, inheritance

I found a strange error in my contract and tried to resolve it, but it's so unreasonable.

```
contract parentContract {

    uint num = 1;

    function setNum(uint _n) public returns(uint) {
        num = _n;
        return num;
    }
    function getNum() public view returns(uint) {
        return num;
    }
}
```

---

```
import "./parentContract.sol"

contract childContract is parentContract {
    /* Same name but IDE don't report error
    *function getNum() public view returns(uint) {
    *    return num;
    *}   
    */

    function getNum2() public view returns(uint) {
        return num;
    }
    function getNum3() public view returns(uint) {
        return getNum();
    }
    function getNum4() public view returns(uint) {
        return parentContract.getNum();
    }
}
```

They are simple contracts in two .sol files for testing. I hope the `getNum2()` will return the `num` in `parentContract`, but it always return `1` that I set first.  Both `getNum3()`/`getNum4()` get the same result with `getNum2()`.

I used truffle V4.1.14 for deploying. Here are my code interacted with contract, in the Command Terminal.

```
parentContract.deployed().then(function(instance){return instance.setNum(2);});**//Set the num**
parentContract.deployed().then(function(instance){return instance.getNum();}).then(function(value){ return value.toNumber();});**//Get num in parentContract**
childContract.deployed().then(function(instance){return instance.getNum2();}).then(function(value){ return value.toNumber();});**//Get num through child**
childContract.deployed().then(function(instance){return instance.getNum2.call();}).then(function(value){ return value.toNumber();});**//Another method, use call() for testing, same with above.**`
```

Comment: Have your run `setNum` of `parentContract`?

Comment: Of course, I also tried `getNum()` of parent and it worked well.

Comment: On Remix, contract is working fine. It is returning updated values.

Comment: Please share your test code.

Comment: I'm not sure, you mean the code interacted with contract ( of truffle) ? I add them above now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parentContract.deployed()` and `childContract.deployed()` are two different instances.

You are calling `instance.setNum(2)` only for the first instance.

So the value of `num` in the second instance remains `1`.

And `instance.getNum2()` returns that value.

Comment: I got it! So for inheritance I just need to interact with the final-child contract, all parents codes will be copied, I know what that means now.  Thank you so much!